# Referencing a column created with a sub query in same select statment

Tags: sql-server-2008

Right now I'm converting a really old Access 97 program into .NET. Some stuff ports well, other stuff, not so much. Right now I'm converting a query for a report.

```
DECLARE @CLIENT as varchar(16) = 'ClientsName'
DECLARE @StartDate as date = '2016-02-01'
DECLARE @EndDate as date = '2016-02-29'

SELECT DISTINCT NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NewHireList WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION ) AS NumberHired,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NewHireList WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION AND CONTROL IS NOT NULL AND Qualify <> 'U') AS NumberReferred,
(NumberReferred/NumberHired) AS PercentRefered
FROM (SELECT * FROM NewHireList WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT = @CLIENT AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate) AS NewHirePostProcessed;
```

I'm having trouble with the math part that references the other columns of the table.

```
(NumberReferred/NumberHired) AS PercentRefered
```

I'm getting the error that the columns don't exist.

```
SQL Error (207) Invalid column name 'NumberQualified'
Invalid column name 'NumberReferred'
```

I'm assuming this is one of the quirks from Access that allowed the old one to work. Is there an easy way around this that doesn't have me redoing the sub queries in every math part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called [`common table expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (CTE for short).
The idea is that you define a query and then can use the result set it returns as a base for the next sql statement.
It's basically a different way to use derived tables.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION, 
                    (   
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                    ) AS NumberHired,
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                        AND CONTROL IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Qualify <> 'U'
                    ) AS NumberReferred,

    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM NewHireList 
        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT = @CLIENT 
        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate
    ) AS NewHirePostProcessed
)

SELECT  NumberHired, 
        NumberReferred, 
        (NumberReferred/NumberHired) AS PercentRefered
FROM cte
```

It's equivalent to this way, though easier to read:

```
SELECT  NumberHired, 
        NumberReferred, 
        (NumberReferred/NumberHired) AS PercentRefered
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION, 
                    (   
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                    ) AS NumberHired,
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                        AND CONTROL IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Qualify <> 'U'
                    ) AS NumberReferred,

    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM NewHireList 
        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT = @CLIENT 
        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate
    ) AS NewHirePostProcessed
) derived
```

You can even use a chain of common table expressions, like this:

```
;WITH NewHirePostProcessed AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM NewHireList 
    WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT = @CLIENT 
    AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
    AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate
)
, cte As 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION, 
                    (   
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                    ) AS NumberHired,
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NewHireList 
                        WHERE NewHireList.CLIENT=@CLIENT 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE > @StartDate 
                        AND NewHireList.DOHIRE < @EndDate 
                        AND NewHirePostProcessed.LOCATION = LOCATION 
                        AND CONTROL IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Qualify <> 'U'
                    ) AS NumberReferred,

    FROM NewHirePostProcessed
)

SELECT  NumberHired, 
        NumberReferred, 
        (NumberReferred/NumberHired) AS PercentRefered
FROM cte
```

Comment: How do I declare variables with Common Table Expression?

Comment: You declare them before the cte, and you can use them inside the cte jast as you would in any other query

Comment: My apologies, HeidiSQL was sending the command in segments. Once I set it to do it in batches it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@Zohar is correct (+1). Just because the underlying query is horrible, here's a further simplification--though you'd need to review the results and ensure its accuracy:

```
;WITH cteBase
 as (--  Generate summaries
     select
        LOCATION
       ,count(*)  AS  NumberHired
       ,sum(case
              when CONTROL is not null and Qualify <> 'U' then 1
              else 0
            end)  AS  NumberReferred
      from NewHireList
      where CLIENT = @CLIENT
       and DOHIRE > @StartDate
       and DOHIRE < @EndDate
      group by LOCATION
    )
 select
   LOCATION
  ,NumberHired
  ,NumberReferred
  ,NumberReferred / NumberHired  AS  PercentRefered
 from cteBase
```

Comment: Well, in Access 97 they didn't have the great tools we have today...  but reading your query it seems to be equivalent. Of course, the OP must test it against the current query. I didn't even think about getting into the query details, +1 for that.

Comment: This errors out with "SQL Error (156): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Comment: Whoops! I just reordered the `where` and the `group by`.